# convert datetime column to a zero-based months. 0 is Jan and 11 is Dec

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have a datetime column that I want to 'stringify' it  using [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), the problem is I want the months to be zero-based i.e. `0=January`, `11=December`.

What I've tried is after I 'stringified' the column and called [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace) on it by passing a regex and a callable to convert the month to a number and subtract one from it and then convert it back to a string

Why do I want it to be zero-based?
because this data going to be consumed by Google Charts and it requires date represented as string to be [zero-based](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation)

here is the code, is there a better solution?

```
month_regex = r",(0[1-9]|1[0-2])"
#                vvv  ->  month_regex
format = "Date(%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S)"

print(df["start"].dtype)  # float64   represents an epoch

# convert epoch to datetime and then to string with the given format
df["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start"]//1000, unit="s").dt.strftime(format)

print(df["start"])  # Date(2022,05,24,00,00,00)

df["start"] = df["start"].str.replace(
    month_regex,
    lambda match: "," + str(int(match[0][1:]) - 1),
    1,  # first occurrence only
    regex=True)

print(df["start"])  # Date(2022,4,24,00,00,00)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use string formatting to achieve the same result.

```py
df = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["2022-01-01"]))

# We extract the month as integer and subtract one from it. Then do string formatting
df.apply(lambda x: x.strftime("Date(%Y,%i,%d,%H,%M,%S)") % (x.month-1))
```

Comment: it seems doesn't work: _ValueError: Invalid format string_

Comment: Check you datetime string format it shud be %Y,%i,%d,%H,%M,%S

Comment: I'v got it, there was a mistake in the code, this one works fine: `df.apply(lambda x: x.strftime("Date(%Y,%%i,%d,%H,%M,%S)") % (x.month-1))` (check '%%i')

Answer (score 1):

I would make your regex only capable of matching the `month` part of the `Date(...)` string by using a lookbehind for `Date` followed by a `(`, 4 digits and a comma:

```
(?<=Date\(\d{4},)\d\d
```

Then you need only worry about replacing the match:

```py
df['start'].str.replace('(?<=Date\(\d{4},)\d\d', lambda m:f'{int(m[0])-1:02d}', regex=True)
```

Note I've used an `f-string` to ensure the output month value has 2 digits (i.e. `04` instead of `4`), if that isn't necessary just use:

```py
df['start'].str.replace('(?<=Date\(\d{4},)\d\d', lambda m:str(int(m[0])-1))
```